# Cómo puedo submitir un form en React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

estoy intentando crear un formulario en React. Es la primera vez que lo hago, y aunque está todo creado, no sé como hacer que se submita a algún lado. Supongo que me falta algo de back end para decirle a dónde debería enviar el form, pero no sé cómo hacer eso. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Esto lo importo en App.js y después renderizo todo en index.js
Creería que el código está bien, o por lo menos es igual que lo que vi en un curso, pero cuando hago click en el botón no pasa nada, pero tiene sentido ya que no le estoy diciendo a dónde se debería mandar el form. Estuve buscando alguna respuesta de qué tengo que hacer pero no encontré nada claro, así que ya no sé qué hacer. Gracias!

Este es el código que tengo por ahora:

````
import React from "react"

export default function Contact(){
    const[formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            text: ""
        }
    )

    function handleChange(event){
        const{name, value, type} = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return{
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: value
            }
        })
    }

    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    return(
        <section className="contactSection">
            <h2>Contact Me</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="data">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name="name"
                        value={formData.name}
                    />

                    <input
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name="email"
                        value={formData.email}
                    />
                </div>      
                <textarea
                    value={formData.text}
                    placeholder="Leave me a message"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="text"
                />

                <button className="send">Submit</button>

            </form>

        </section>
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

lo que hace es que mediante fetch envia los datos al endpoint y espera una respuesta para que tu en el frontEnd puedas
procesar dichos datos y puedar realizar una accion ya sea redireccionar a otra vista o simplemente mostrar un mensage(falta validar los inputs que no esten vacios)

pero depende de un endpoint en un servidor que te valide
los datos y reaccione segun lo que quieras hacer con los datos(verificar usuario y clave o enviar un correo, etc)

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  
    e.preventDefault()
      let url = 'url de backend que procese los datos que envias por parametro'
      let token = 'si tienes un token como seguridad en el backen o lo omites'
      const fetchData = await fetch(url,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'authorization': token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            data: formData,
          })
        })
    
        let response = fetchData.json()
        if(response.status === 200){
          /** hacer algo si la respuesta y la validadion de los datos es correcta */
          window.location.href = '/redireccion'
          /** si usas react router */
          <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
        }else{
          /** generar un mensaje de error en caso de que la validacion de datos fuera incorrecta */
          window.alert('los datos son incorrectos verificalos')
        }

}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces todo eso debería poner antes de iniciar con el return. Lo que no sé es que URL debería usar, ya que esto es solo para un proyecto que voy ejecutar desde GitHub, es para poder armar mi portfolio.

Comment: te aconsejo que busques informacion o videos de como crear aplicaciones web con reactjs y nextjs , estas dos herramientas juntas te dan la posibilidad de levantar la pagina y un servidor todo en uno es muy util para empezar.